# Difference between the working process of `mclapply` and `foreach()` loop

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, doparallel, mclapply

This is a general question out of curiosity. I am using the `doParallel` package for parallel computing.  I use these packages for the simulation purposes.

What I observed is that when I was using the `foreach` loop for the simulation current usage memory in Rstudio rose drastically (4+GiB) and the Rstudio crashed sometime.

Now I am shifting to `parallel::mclapply` and have done the same simulation again but surprisingly there is no problem and current usage memory doesn't rise much (10+MiB).

I don't understand what is happening internally in the code. I expect a detailed explanation of the above processes.

`sessionInfo()` for my R is

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
```

and OS is MacOS.

`doParallel` package version 1.0.17.

RStudio version 2023.03.01.

#### Example:

Suppose we are trying to count edges from a Erdos-Renyi graph. I am  trying to simulate the graph each time and store the edge count value for each simulation.

Codes are the following

```
#ER random graph generator
src1 <- {"#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix ER_AdjMatGEN_cpp(int N, double p){
  NumericMatrix temp(N,N);
  for(int i=0; i< N; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < i; j++){
        temp(i,j) = R::rbinom(1,p);
        temp(j,i) = temp(i,j);
    }
  }
  return temp;
}"}
```

```
Niter <- 10000
#________________
edgeCnt_result1 <- foreach(icount(Niter),
                           v = iter(function() ER_AdjMatGEN_cpp(10000, 0.3)),
                           .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
                             sum(v)
                           }
#___________
edgeCnt_result1 <- do.call(rbind, mclapply(1:Niter, function(i) {v = ER_AdjMatGEN_cpp(N = 10000, 0.3) 
return(sum(v))} , mc.cores = 7))
```

When I try to run the first iteration, Rstudio crashes but when I run the second iteration, it runs properly.

Comment: Please add the final `Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = src1)` to your first code snippet to make it work for those less familiar with `Rcpp`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `mclapply()` code first generates the complete `Niter`-long list and then the `do.call()` rbinds it all together. There is only one allocation of the results vector.

`foreach()` on the other hand uses `.combine` to rbind list elements as they become available, iteratively re-allocating the result vector as it grows.

Instead, use the `.multicombine` and `.maxcombine` parameters of `foreach()`. To mimic the `do.call()`, set the first `TRUE` and the second to `Niter`.

See https://rpubs.com/jimhester/rbind for a more detailed explanation.